# How would better save data like books?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I want to make service where I can read books online. In what manner I could store books for show on site where can read? Is it good to keep in MongoDB? Or just like a files on server (`node.js`) ?

I think it will problem to keep this data on DB, because books doesn't save a line breaks and paragraphs (`String` data type in MongoDB), is it?

How to make pagination?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Description**

There is obviously a number ways you could do this. However, I believe the one decent method would be to store the books as PDFs. The web is usually better at displaying the PDF format compared to other formats.

**Back-end**

Possible backend would a database that stores filenames/paths and names of the books in a table. The application could be (tomcat + apache) that would power a REST API that allows you to access the books thru an endpoint. The application would then provide the front-end with the pdf file of the book.

**Front-End**

Use a plugin like pdfjs that allows you to display the pdf files on the front-end, which will handle the pagination and everything, and allow the user to read the pdf.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So I can use tomcat+apache as a server? Not a node.js? And yes, books will be a `.pdf` format

Comment: You could also use node.js as a backend to do the same thing. Tomcat + Apache was just one suggestion, but by no means the only way nor the best way to do it. Depends on what you want to do. Node.js can handle a lot, and is asynchronous by nature, so at times its harder to debug, but it's much easier to setup than tomcat + apache. My personal opinion is that tomcat + apache is probably more robust, because javascript isn't statically typed, but there are many well known production apps online  that seem to be very well done using node.js. So the choice is yours :)

Comment: No problem...!!

Comment: Can I use something another thing that `pdf.js` ? Because I want to select text to add some word to vocabulary. `pdf.js` generate pdf in canvas, so I can't select words...

Comment: I'm not sure of other libraries, but you can use something like canvas plus to annotate over the pdf?